# Visual Studio 2019 Hot Reload stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, hot-reload

after VS19 update (16.11.18) HotReload function stopped working in my Winform project(.NET 4.7.2).
I try to create a new Form project and HotReload  works fine.
No settings have been changed in the old project, I just updated Visual Studio to latest version from 16.11.14v.
I have check the settings about HR and in DEBUG - XAML HOT RELOAD - ENABLE XAML HOT RELOAD is checked.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way:

- From project properties -> Build -> Allow Unsafe Code -> Remove check.
- Clean solution and Rebuild
- From project properties -> Build -> Allow Unsafe Code -> Add check.
- Rebuild

And HotReload restart working.
If you want use .csproj :

- `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>`
- clean + rebuild
- `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>`
- Rebuild

I don't know why, but it works.